# Is this a valid counterexample that $B$ is not a brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

> Let $U,V$ be two Brownian motions. In class we have seen that if $U$ and $V$ are independent, then $B:=xU+\sqrt{1-x^2}V$ is a Brownian motion for $x\in [-1,1]$.
> Now I asked myself if the independence is really needed. I think so and I would do the following counterexample otherwise:

Let us assume $U=V$ then they are dependent. And $B_t=xU_t+\sqrt{1-x^2}U_t$. Then $$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(B_t,B_s)&=\operatorname{cov}\left(xU_t+\sqrt{1-x^2}U_t,xU_s+\sqrt{1-x^2}U_s\right)\\&=x^2(t\wedge s)+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}(t\wedge s)+(1-x^2)(t\wedge s)\\&=(t\wedge s)+2x\sqrt{1-x^2} (t\wedge s)\\&=(t\wedge s)\left(1+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\end{align}$$We know that $B$ is a Brownian motion iff $\left(1+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=1$ or equivalently $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$ which implies $x=0$ or $x=\pm 1$. But if I take $x\in (-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ then I think that I have found an example which shows that independence is needed.

Is this true or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that Brownian motion must have quadratic variation $\left\langle B \right\rangle_t =t$. Suppose $U$ and $V$ are correlated Brownian motions, so that their quadratic covariation is $\left\langle U, V \right\rangle_t = \rho t$. Let's show that the cases you've identified are indeed the only cases which give you Brownian motion. Here I assume that $(U,V)$ is a $2$-dimensional Brownian motion.

Using the polarisation identities, we get:

\begin{align}
\left\langle B \right\rangle_t &= x^2 \left\langle U \right\rangle_t + (1-x^2)\left\langle V \right\rangle_t + 2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \left\langle U,V \right\rangle_t \\
&= t + 2x \sqrt{1-x^2} \rho t 
\end{align}

This quantity is precisely $t$ when $\rho = 0$ (i.e. under the assumption that $(U,V)$ is 2-dimensional Brownian motion, that $U$ and $V$ are independent), or when $x = \pm 1$, as desired.

Comment: But does this mean that my example above is correct if I take $x\in (-1,1)\setminus \{0\}$ and set $U=V$? So does this shows that if we left independence then we do not necessarily have a brownion motion?

Comment: @user1294729 yes, that is precisely the case where rho is 1